# Applying styles to categorized layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I have categorised a layer so I can attach reference numbers and names to the various points but I would like all the points to have the same colour and only be differentiated by their number.

Unfortunately QGIS automatically sets it to colour each item as part of a range of colours and I can't seem to find a way of making them all the same colour.

Answer (score 2):

The categorising in QGis is so you can have different styling based on certain criteria in the data ('categories' for certain ranges of a parameter in one of the data fields).

If you want them all to look the same, don't go for categorised, but 'single symbol' (bottom left of the 'style' tab in properties, and set the style once. It'll apply to all objects that way.